# Spring configuration bean with defaults and multiple overrides

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot application that has reason to call out to multiple HTTP services.  I would like to be able to configure my Clients with varying options, e.g. socket timeouts, as well as have a default.

Ideally, I could specify properties like this:

```
client.default.socket-timeout=500ms
client.slow-service.socket-timeout=1000ms # it's a bit slower
client.fast-service.socket-timeout=100ms
```

make a simple class like:

```
class ClientConfiguration {
    @Value("${client.<client-name>.socket-timeout:${client.default.socket-timeout:30}}")
    int socketTimeout;
}
```

And then be able to inject:

```
@Inject
public MyService(@Named("slow-service") ClientConfiguration slowServiceConfig) { ... }
```

Normally I set my configuration via `@Value`, but there doesn't appear to be a way to parametrize the key it uses.  Especially not based on the bean name.  I would love to avoid writing tons of boilerplate to create key names and fetch it from a `PropertyResolver` or other manual approach.

Does Spring (4.3.0) or Spring Boot (1.4.0.M3) have any good pattern to address this use case?

Comment: please add an example of what you got now and what you expect to have.

Answer (score 0):

When we had similar requirement, instead of using individual `@Value` all over the code, we created a configuration service per group of keys.

```
@Service
public class SlowClientConfigurationService {

    @Value("${client.slow.property.key}")
    private String slowValue;

    // getters, setters, sanity checks and so on...
}
```

and inject this service, where ever you need slow client configuration, which can provide multiple key values via getter/setters method, and also it keeps the code clean.

```
@Service
public class YourService{

    @Autowire
    private SlowClientConfigurationService configurationService ;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is great, but you have to replicate this code each time for "slow" vs "fast" or any other particular specialization you want!  I want to write the code once and reuse it.